# Prove/disprove that $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2-1)$ is integrally closed in its field of fractions.

Tags: ring-theory

I have seen proofs when the underlying field is $\mathbb{Q}$ instead of $\mathbb{C}$ which involve a certain parametrization of the above ring. Can we use the same proof for $\mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sledge-hammer proof using commutative algebra.

First $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]/(X^2 + Y^2 - 1)$ is regular since $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]/(X^2 + Y^2 - 1) \cong \mathbb{C}[X,X^{-1}]$ and the last ring is obviously regular (e.g. it is the localization of a polynomial ring in one variable).

Now it is also clearly an integral domain (the ideal $(X^2 + Y^2 - 1)$ is prime) and thus we have an integral domain, all of whose localizations at prime ideals are integrally closed (indeed, they are regular local rings, which are normal) and thus $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]/(X^2 + Y^2 - 1)$ is integrally closed, since being integrally closed is a local property for integral domains (see for example *Atiyah-Macdonald* 5.13)

Comment: Of course, geometrically, the ring is integrally closed since it is the coordinate ring of a smooth variety.